# Getting the second max value of col2 while being grouped by col1

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a corner here...

The background:

```
TABLE myrecord (
 id     int         # primary key
 name   varchar(32) # test name
 d_when varchar(8)  # date in yyyymmdd string format
)
```

Content:

```
id    name     d_when
100   Alan     20110201
101   Dave     20110304
102   Alan     20121123
103   Alan     20131001
104   Dave     20131002
105   Bob      20131004
106   Mike     20131101
```

In layman terms, I want to figure out who is a "returner" and when was his last (i.e., 'penultimate') visit.
something like the over enthusiastic:

```
SELECT SECOND_MAX(id), CORRESPONDING(d_when) 
FROM myrecord 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING count(name)>1;
```

result expected:

```
101   Dave     20110304 
102   Alan     20121123
```

I tried the following so far.

```
SELECT T1.id, t1.name, T1.d_when 
FROM myrecord t1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id), 
    COUNT(id) cn 
    WHERE cn>1 
    ORDER BY d_when DESC)
```

but something is clearly not right here.

Comment: define 'returner' more clearly?

Comment: you are right, by last, I meant penultimate.  'returner' as in person who comes back into record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why is the second last id necessary?

if it's not:

```
SELECT MAX(id), name, MAX(d_when)
FROM myrecord
    GROUP BY name 
    HAVING count(name)>1
```

if it is:

```
SELECT name, max(id), max(d_when)
FROM myrecord
WHERE 
-- get only the names that have more then one occurrence
name in (
    SELECT name
    FROM myrecord
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
-- filter out the max id's
AND id NOT IN(
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM myrecord
    GROUP BY name
)
GROUP BY name
```

or even better (thanks to @Andomar for the mention):

```
SELECT name, max(id), max(d_when)
FROM myrecord
WHERE 
-- filter out the max id's, this will also filter out those with one record
AND id NOT IN(
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM myrecord
    GROUP BY name
)
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I'm trying to get if one of the 'myrecord's recognized by name has a previous history. If I use max, I'll get only the most recent one... which defies the purpose.

Comment: try the second example (I didn't actually run it)

Comment: Beautifully thought out! Thx.

Comment: Really? - looks unnecessarily cumbersome to me - but whatever floats your boat!

Comment: The `name in (...` part is superfluous.  A name with only one record is already filtered out by the second subquery.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll add another example without the `name IN (` part, it is much more elegant that way

Comment: Surgical. I was looking for a solution first, then a relatively non-complex one. And I must say that, once more, there's no problem that can stand the sustained assault of mind. It's a beauty. Kudos. Thx Andomar for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.name=x.name 
   AND y.d_when >= x.d_when 
 GROUP 
    BY x.name 
     , x.d_when 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: tortured. But about 20x faster than the previous answer. I love it. Thx

Comment: If performance is an issue then there are other, faster methods.

Comment: Wouldn't this return multiple rows with the same name if there are more then 3 rows with the same name in the table?

Comment: The count for those rows would, in each case, be a number higher than 2!

Comment: @movod: if you're interested in performance, check out S. M. 's answer

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, for retrieving all those who have made second visit and their second visited date.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
   @ID:=CASE WHEN @Name <> Name THEN 1 ELSE @ID+1 END AS rn,
   @Name:=Name AS Name,
   ID, d_when
FROM
  (SELECT ID, Name, d_when
   FROM myrecord
   ORDER BY Name asc, d_when asc
  ) rec1,   (SELECT @ID:= 0) rec1_id, (SELECT @Name:= 0) rec1_nm
) rec
where rec.rn=2
```

Output:

```
rn  Name    ID  d_when
2   Dave    104 20131002
2   Alan    102 20121123
```

Comment: But MySQL does not support `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @Andomar updated the post for MySQL equivalent statement, I've overlooked this tag in the post. Will make note of it for future post. thnx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `id` column ascends over time, you can select the second-highest `d_when` per name like:

```
select  name
,       d_when
from    YourTable yt1
where   id in
        (
        select  max(id)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   id not in
                (
                select  max(id)
                from    YourTable yt3
                group by
                        name
                )
        group by
                name
        )
```

Comment: the complexity is a bit too high (SEL(SEL(SEL...))) I might have to borrow some petaflops from the chinese's new supercomputer. But it certainly does the job.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select * from 
> myrecord
> where id in (
>     SELECT max(id)
>     FROM myrecord 
>     WHERE id not in (SELECT MAX(id)
>         FROM myrecord   
>         GROUP BY name 
>         HAVING count(name)>1)
>     group by name )
> ```

Comment: This is the exact same query from the question?

Comment: same answer as Andomar earlier. Works, but too complex. Processor hog.  C/o Marcelo's answer.